# How to create this arrow with letters above and below?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How to create this arrow with letters above and below?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The `mathtools` package offers a wide variety of arrows, which can have content above and below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document} 
$\xleftrightarrow[\mathcal{F}^{-1}]{\mathcal{F}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\xleftrightarrow[F^{-1}]{F}
\]
\end{document}
```

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Above_and_below or [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)-documentation for more variants.

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).