# How to draw an arrow with letter above it to denote a path in graph?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to draw an arrow with letter above it using latex just like below:
[image: Arrow with letter above it]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173938/how-to-create-this-arrow-with-letters-above-and-below?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[ u \mathrel{\mathop{\rightsquigarrow}^{p}} v \]
\end{document}
```

[image]